# Do I need to protect login?

Tags: php, mysql, captcha

I have login page. Do I need to protect it with Captcha or how should I handle it?

For example, if person knows an username, he can use curl or whatever and try to guess passwords many times. It will use many MySQL queries and it will eat my resources.

So, should I use Captcha for login? Or maybe I should store how many times person tried to guess the password with $_SESSION and if he guessed 10 times password wrong, then I would show Captcha? Is it safe to use such a information in $_SESSION? Maybe I should allow person to enter login only every 10 seconds also with $_SESSION? Would it be 100% safe? Or what would you suggest me?

**EDIT: Please read my comment under Eljakim's post.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't go for the session approach.

A captcha may help, but it will annoy your normal users.

You may wish to keep track in your database of how many invalid logins have been tried from a specific IP-address or a specific username within (say) the last 10 minutes. If it goes over a specific threshold, just block that username or IP-address for a while.

Don't do this in the session! An attacker will probably not send the cookie that supports the session, or can just spoof them.

Comment: +1 just use a table to store login attempts, and don't store that in a cookie. If you're lazy you could add sleep(4) to your login script.php and that should slow bruteforce attacks significantly..

Comment: @Eljakim: if I do it, I still will need to check user's data in database and it will eat lots of hosting's resources, right? And I just realized I can't actually use sleep, because I use ajax to login, so it can send many requestes to that page?

Comment: @hey, well, the resources are pretty low to run one query. And a real hacker won't use you Ajax code! A real hacker will go around that and will bang on your PHP script directly.

Answer (score 2):

3 things:

1. Use Recaptcha (run by google) More info [HERE](http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/php.html)
2. Do allow only certain number (10) of login attempts per hour from a unique IP address before timing out for say an hour or two.
3. Set a cookie when a successful login happens, and don't show the Captcha if the user has this cookie to not annoy regular visitors.

This will take care of all of the hacking attempts. Based on your traffic and how many hacking attempts you receive, you might want to play with the numbers.

Comment: An hour of two is completely unnecessary. A simple delay of a few seconds between each login attempt makes any bruteforce attempts completely invaluable.

Comment: @hoppa depends on who's writing the attack program/script. I've written scrappers that have waited minutes before each call, so this is important to consider, as the cost of running a scrapper/brute force program is very low, and once you set it, you can forget it until it does achieve what you want to achieve.

Comment: The point is that brute forcing any decent login will take a huge amount of attempts. If you have to wait, say 5 seconds, after a failed attempt, this only allows 12 attempts per minute which is only 720 attempts per hour. For a 8 letter password consisting of [A-Za-z0-9] there are 2.18×10¹⁴ possibilities....

Comment: After downloading the top 1000 most commonly used passwords, you can run that in under 1.5 hours, even with 5 seconds delay, because as everybody knows, not everybody randomly generates their passwords or makes them really secure.

Comment: Even then, simply doubling the delay after each failed login attempt would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would not opt for a Captcha to handle multiple failed login attempts.  Instead, you can keep a counter in your database and increment it on each unsuccessful login attempt.  When you reach your determined number of failures (5 or 10 or whatever), you can create a lockout period or ten minutes in your database during which you won't accept logins from that user.

This protects your users from password brute-forcing.  `$_SESSION` will not be effective here, because the tools used for brute-forcing won't likely accept or honor session cookies.

Answer (score 1):

Might I suggest adding a call to `sleep()` to add some extra frustration for login loaders?

Even a mere two seconds of sleep will cumulatively add to the level of time needed to mount a brute-force attack like you are describing.

Comment: it seems very nice idea, what do others think about it?

Comment: i just added that as a comment... I don't recommend it, maybe WITH recording someone's IP.. so if they have a failed attempt you add sleep(5).

Comment: Definitely better to make the sleep only implement against those believed to be attackers.  I just thought I'd give the outline of the idea :)

Comment: Unless you're going to sleep even when the password is correct, this won't work. Any attacker with brains will use multiple threads and simply close the connection if it doesn't get a successful login within 1 or 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

DO not worry about your mysql queries, but worry about user's password. Insert line to DB everytime user tries to login (and fails) and select these lines everytime he/she tries to login again) if login attempts > 5 -> restrict to login

Comment: Is it the best way? Are my ideas with $_SESSION not safe? Thank you.

Comment: yes you can also store his attempts in session, but he could clear cookies everytime he tries to log in

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple layers of security here.  One option would be to only allow, say, 5 login attempts every X minutes.  This will stop most brute forcers.  (You can also ban known brute forcers via IP or whatever)  Adding a CAPTCHA would obviously be even more help.  After however many wrong tries, just display an obscured image using some of PHP's image features, for example.  The more features you add, the safer.  Do note though that a CAPTCHA is a hassle for many legitimate users.

Answer (score 0):

It is not really safe to store the try-count in $_SESSION. If I am not accepting your cookies in my bruteforce-script i will get a new session for each request.

If you are trying to prevent any kind of DOS attacks: Limit the amount of requests per IP to an adequate amount per time interval.

If you are just trying to prevent bruteforcing passwords: Use captcha or store the count of failed logins in your DB. (Maybe block a User after 3 failed attempts for an hour or so?)

Answer (score 0):

I allways choose one of two options, either pin code like - three failed password, and you email the user a new password.
Or, have a cooldown periode of 2^(failed logins - 5) - will very fast give huge delay. Ie. 7 failed will give 2^(7-5) = 4 secs delay aso.